# Reload component in angular 4 or destroy datatable

Tags: datatables, angular2-routing, angular-datatables, angular4-router

I am using a Datatable to show the records of members of an organization. Firstly it loads data from the API but when I add new member it gives me error:

> Datatable can not be initialized again

I want to reload that component or any other solution to this problem

[image: you can find detail code in picture]

```
setTimeout(function(){                                                               
  this.table  =  $('#tableid').DataTable({ stateSave:true, autoWidth: true, dom: 
  'Bfrtip' });      
},3000);
```

Comment: datatable can not be initialize twice

Comment: I set your image to display. When including code it is best to include it as text rather than an image. An image of code is much less useful to the folks you are asking to help you out. By copying the relevant code into the question you are showing respect for their time.